# XML for all screens

Tags: android, xml

I have a layout with 8 buttons 2 image views and 2 text views. On my device (Galaxy S) it fits but on devices with smaller screen the bottom side is not appearing.How could I adapt my layout for all screens?

Comment: Couldn't Understood the Problem,Please be more descriptive and add Code/Snap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your app to support all kind of screen sizes, 
you need to create different layout xml file for each kind of the screen types.
place each one of the above on resource folder:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
```

on run time - android will automatically choose the right resource according to the device's screen type

you can read more about it on -
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

use RelativeLayouts or LinearLayouts with `layout_weight` property. If you can post some xml, i would give you more suggestions.

The problem occurs generally with the ImageViews mostly, as they occupy more space on smaller screen, since smaller screen has lesser no.of pixels per inch. It's a general practice to restrict the sizes in `dp`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define more layouts with different width and height.Then check the height and width and density of device and use that specific layout for that device.

Answer (score 1):

Use screen dependent pixels dp and sp. Design a different layout for different screen sizes. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html <-- refer here

For most width and sometimes height problems you can use layout_weight to assign the exact ratio catered for each View.

If there is no other choice and that your layout have to be that way you might want to consider using a ScrollView to wrap your parent layout so that they can be scrollable. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html <-- refer here.

Good luck.